# How To create DigitalOcean service endpoint connection in AzureDevops when using DigitalOcean Tools task in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops, digital-ocean

I am trying to upload build apk file in DigitalOcean by using Azure DevOps.

In AzureDevops,we have task called DigitalOcean Tools by using this we can upload the files in DigitalOcean.Below is the link for your reference.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marcelo-formentao.digitalocean-tools&ssr=false#overview

I installed that task in my organization.

First it will ask for to create DigitalOcean Connection by using service endpoint in azure devops.

I Search in Service endpoint in Azure DevOps i didn't find Service connection for Digital Ocean(apart that I found gitlab,ssh,azure..eg i found for all these Service Connection).

My Question is which service connector i need to used for Digital Ocean?

Please help me on this
[image: Azure Devops Services]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any solution for this one

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

DigitalOcean Connection: It's based on AWS configuration (only Access Key ID and Secret Key ID is required).

You can choose AWS connection type to create DigitalOcean service endpoint connection in Azure DevOps. And fill the Access Key ID and Secret Key ID that you can get from your DigitalOcean.

Result

[image: DigitalOcean connection]

**UPDATE**

If you didn't find AWS end point connection, you should install `AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps` extension in marketplace.Url:[AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools)

After installing the extension, you would see AWS connection type in your service connection.I test in my devops and it works.

[image: AWS Connection Type]

Comment: Hi Dou Xu-MSFT, Thanks for Responding and answering my question.

Comment: Above i shared screenshots which it shows available service end point connections. Here i didn't find aws end point connection.Can you guide me How To get AWS end Point Service Connection

Comment: For AWS end Point Service Connection i need to install any task for that

Comment: @mohankrishna I've updated my answer. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Does it work for you? If it helps, just a remind of accept an answer, this will help other users who has the same issue.